# Can you use utf-8 or HTML entity escapes (hex) codes in schema.org microdata values?

Tags: seo, google-plus, html-encode, microdata, schema.org

I often use escape codes in meta title and meta description, and they render correctly in Google SERPS ... but ...

Can you use them (like an `&mdash`; for example) in schema.org microdata values? I want these characters to be passed and render correctly in G+ snippets, as discussed here:

https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/

... what about utf-8 ?? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly legal according to the specs, and I would expect it to work fine.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like you are correct. I am looking at listings in Google Product search results to see how they markup the microdata. I see `itemprop="name"` values with hex characters, and they are rendering normally. thank you!